# Adding additional linq where clauses based on variables

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, ienumerable

I'm trying to add additional where clauses to a linq query depending on what variable results are passed to a function.

```
var allFeedback = 
    from f in _unitOfWork.Feedback.All()
    join b in _unitOfWork.Bookings.All() on f.CourseBookingID equals b.CourseBookingID
    join cb in _unitOfWork.CourseBookings.All() on f.CourseBookingID equals cb.CourseBookingID
    where b.SiteID == siteID && b.Date >= fromDate && b.Date <= to && b.CancelledID == null
    select f;

if (courseID > 0)
{
    allFeedback.Where(f => f.CourseBooking.CourseID == courseID);
}

if (facilitatorID == 0)
{
    allFeedback.Where(f => f.CourseBooking.FacilitatorID == null);
}
else if (facilitatorID > 0)
{
    allFeedback.Where(f => f.CourseBooking.FacilitatorID == facilitatorID);
}

allFeedback.ToList();
```

I want to add the where clauses to the original query "allFeedback" but when the query is executed the additional clauses are ignored.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes its possible just do :

```
if (courseID > 0)
{
    allFeedback = allFeedback.Where(f => f.CourseBooking.CourseID == courseID);
}

if (facilitatorID == 0)
{
    allFeedback = allFeedback.Where(f => f.CourseBooking.FacilitatorID == null);
}
else if (facilitatorID > 0)
{
    allFeedback = allFeedback.Where(f => f.CourseBooking.FacilitatorID == facilitatorID);
}
```

You just forgot to assign the result to the variable.

Comment: Amazing thank you so much! :) I'll mark this as the accepted answer when it allows me, thanks again.